# You are using the component wrong shyNavBarManager

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I'm trying to implent shyNavBarManager in my app:

I have a UITableview in storyboard and trying to use shyNavNarManager:

```
   self.shyNavBarManager.scrollView = self.tbPertos;
```

but I'm getting :

> NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'You are using the component wrong... Please see the README file.'

Comment: You could try following the suggestion that the error message gives.  See "Remarks" here: https://github.com/telly/TLYShyNavBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer isn't to check `self.tbPertos`, but instead, what is `self`. It must be a `UIViewController` subclass, since you are accessing the `shyNavBarManager`. However, it must be part of a navigation controller before you can start utilizing the component. So, move your code to `viewDidLoad` or somewhere after the component gets added to a navigation controller.

*Note: I developed that library*

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation:

```
NSAssert(navbar != nil, @"You are using the component wrong... Please see the README file.");
```

So it would seem that the navigation bar you are trying to assign here does not exist or is not initialized. *See self.tbPertos*

Comment: self.tbPertos is a UITableView